# left join with condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I do have 2 tables students and attendance.

Students

```
student_id   name
----------  -----
1          | A
2          | B
3          | C
```

Attendance

```
id | date       | student_id
------------------------------
1  | 2015-12-05 | 1
2  | 2015-12-05 | 2
3  | 2015-12-05 | 3
4  | 2015-12-06 | 2
5  | 2015-12-06 | 3
```

I need the details of students who are absent on  2015-12-06.

The result should be : 1 | A

I know the query I am trying is wrong but it should be something like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM students s 
left join attendance a on s.id=a.student_id 
where date='2015-12-06' and a.id IS NULL
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Change where to and. Change and to where

Comment: Exactly, I wanted to do this only. Just misunderstood

Answer (score -2):

I guess this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE student_id NOT IN
(SELECT s.student_id
FROM Students s
LEFT JOIN Attendance a
ON s.student_id = a.student_id
WHERE a.date LIKE '2015-12-06'
GROUP BY s.student_id);
```

Not tested, but i belive you got the idea

//NOTE: I guess you can get rid of the `GROUP BY s.student_id`part

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a ton. You made my day. I absolutely forgot to use subquery :) This worked for me - SELECT * FROM Students WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT a.student_id FROM Attendance a WHERE a.date = '2015-12-06')

Comment: 'Left join x where x' = a basic misunderstanding of how joins operate in MySQL